# How to add 'active' to menu parent when submenu already has 'active'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using the jquery code I attached in the post below. I don't know if the code is missing something, but so far no luck. If you can recreate a new coding, please help out.
Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wsite-menu-wrap ul li .wsite-menu-subitem.active').parent().closest('.sidebar-nav .dropdown').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav sidebar-nav">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="wsite-menu-default">
      <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
        <div class="dropdown open">
          <span class="dropdown-link"><a href="/women" class="wsite-menu-item **ADD 'ACTIVE' HERE**">WOMEN</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
          <ul class="wsite-menu">
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="/accessory" class="wsite-menu-subitem ***active***">ACCESSORY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="/dress" class="wsite-menu-subitem ">DRESS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to add `active` class? To the `ul`? When `li` has the `active` class?

Comment: Summary: The submenu following: class="wsite-menu-subitem active" has an active class, and I'd like to add another "active" class to

Comment: I'd like to add "active" class to <span class="dropdown-link"><a href="/women" class="wsite-menu-item **ADD 'ACTIVE' HERE**">WOMEN</a></span>

Comment: POST IS NOW SOLVED. Thank you to all for outstanding help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate back to the closest `li.has-submenu` which will be the root parent for `submenu` and then find the related `a` tag as below and `addClass`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wsite-menu-wrap ul li .wsite-menu-subitem.active').closest('li.has-submenu').find('.dropdown-link a').addClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav sidebar-nav">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="wsite-menu-default">
      <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
        <div class="dropdown open">
          <span class="dropdown-link"><a href="/women" class="wsite-menu-item">WOMEN</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
          <ul class="wsite-menu">
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="/accessory" class="wsite-menu-subitem active">ACCESSORY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="/dress" class="wsite-menu-subitem ">DRESS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: You can possibly upvote and mark this as answer if it helped.. :)

Comment: I tried. But then it gave me this.... "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.wsite-menu-subitem.active').parents().find('a.wsite-menu-item').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: For this code, the class "active" was added to all links. So close!! :( thank you

Comment: I tried another code, and it is working now. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: @AAShakil, I am not saying my answer, anyone's answer helpful!! and he said that working !!

Answer (score 0):

I think searching up and down the DOM tree is not a good practice. jQuery was built to hook by class or id. For each submenu item I added a class 'womens', 'mens' and then added and ID of the same name's to the header link.  When you click any submenu item it highlights the header title.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .active {
    color: orange;
  }
</style>

<div class="nav sidebar-nav">
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="wsite-menu-default">
      <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
        <div class="dropdown open">
          <span class="dropdown-link">
            <a id="womens" href="#" class="wsite-menu-item active">WOMEN</a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
          <ul class="wsite-menu">
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap">
              <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-subitem womens active">ACCESSORY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-subitem womens">DRESS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-subitem womens">SHOES</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap has-submenu">
        <div class="dropdown open">
          <span class="dropdown-link">
            <a id="mens" href="#" class="wsite-menu-item">MEN</a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="wsite-menu-wrap">
          <ul class="wsite-menu">
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-subitem mens">WATCHES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-subitem mens">PANTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="wsite-menu-subitem-wrap ">
              <a href="#" class="wsite-menu-subitem mens">SHOES</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.wsite-menu-subitem').on('click', function(){
      $('.wsite-menu-subitem').removeClass('active')
      let self = $(this)
      self.addClass('active')
      if (self.hasClass('mens')) {
        $('#mens').addClass('active')
        $('#womens').removeClass('active')
      }
      if (self.hasClass('womens')) {
        $('#womens').addClass('active')
        $('#mens').removeClass('active')
      }
    })

  });
</script>
```